# How to place elements with different dimensions(Height & Width) in a random order in a asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

I faced problems when multiple elements(say 50) are given with similar and different dimensions(1*1,1*2,3*4 etc) and when you need to include all these elements in one page independent of the screen size in a random order.

Comment: Can you show us some code on what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a masonry layout.

Check out Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Here's a simple example

```
    <div id="container">
         <div class="item">...</div>
         <div class="item">...</div>
         <div class="item">...</div>
         ...
    </div>

$('#container').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector : '.item',
  layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});
```